# How do I flatten this logo with overlay blending mode in Sketch?

Tags: logo, svg, sketch-app, blending

I made this logo, but I want to flatten it so that it's always the same no matter what the background color is. How do I do this? It consists of three ovals with the "overlay" blending mode. It's made in Sketch.
Thanks!

[image: this is the logo in question]

Comment: Illustrator has a **Flatten Transparency** feature, not sure about Sketch though.

Answer (score 1):

No need to flatten. Insert a piece of 50% grey (R=G=B=128) behind it with blending mode normal. A perfectly fitting piece can be made as boolean union of the copies of those shapes.